# Domain class inheriting abstract non-domain class

Tags: inheritance, grails, grails-orm

I have an application running well with Grails 1.1 (yeah, it's 2016 and this application has never been updated). I'm currently trying to update it to the most recent version of Grails. But I'm trying to update from 1.1 to 1.2.5, then to 1.3.7, then to 2.4.4 and so on. I think that it would be too many changes to be done if I attempted to upgrade directly to a newer version.

So, when updating to 1.2.5, I had an issue I can't figure out how to solve. First, some of my domain classes were mapped through hbm.xml. After a problem with duplicate mapping, I migrated all the hbm.xml to normal mapping inside the domain classes. It worked for all of them, except for 5 of them. When running my application, no GORM generated methods can be found. They all throw groovy.lang.MissingMethodException for those 4 domain classes.

I noticed the only difference between these 4 domain classes and the others that are working is that they all extends from abstract non-domain classes. The hierarchy is as follows:

Inside /src/groovy:

- abstract class Event
- abstract class IssuerEvent extends Event
- abstract class ReceiverEvent extends Event

Inside /grails-app/domain:

- class Cancellation extends IssuerEvent
- class EPECEvent extends IssuerEvent
- class Correction extends IssuerEvent
- class ReceiverManifestation extends ReceiverEvent

The abstract classes are just including some properties (that are inherited and mapped in the domain classes) e some abstract and non-abstract methods. I need it for the polymorphism.

Why is this problem happening? The inheritance was working with grails 1.1 and I've seen recent answers talking about this approach of creating abstract classes inside /src/groovy. Is there a specific bug in grails 1.2.5 regarding this issue?

Comment: I think you're setting yourself up for a lot of unnecessary pain and frustration doing many incremental upgrades. For a jump this big you should go directly to 3.1.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith, but to do that, I'd have to make so many changes that it'd be too confusing to upgrade everything, don't you think?

Comment: It's not really code revision. Meaning once you are three highly unlikely you will step back and if you do it may be to compare. So really what Burt said above